# Vue.js interpolation when using vue.js through script tag

Tags: vue.js

I am unable to work with string interpolation using vue.js as simple as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

While this works fine in [jsfiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/wfh904sz) , what wrong with my script ?

Comment: please disregards this question, since I am passing the template through twig template engine , that is striping those `{{}}` braces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the delimiters to `[[]]` :

```
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>[[ message ]]</p>
</div>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]']
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
        }
    })
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to write data properties:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
  }
})
```